# Cannot Build gem for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I cannot build a Ruby gem for some reason. I'm new to Ruby so not really sure what exactly is happening.

#### This is the output:

```
$ bundle exec rake release

rake aborted!
/Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/deprecated.rb:19:in `block in quick_emit': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2286:in `block (2 levels) in to_yaml'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/coder.rb:36:in `map'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2285:in `block in to_yaml'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/deprecated.rb:19:in `call'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/deprecated.rb:19:in `block in quick_emit'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2286:in `block (2 levels) in to_yaml'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych/coder.rb:36:in `map'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2285:in `block in to_yaml'
     ... 9618 levels...
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:170:in `process_args'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:130:in `run'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:60:in `run'
    from /Users/kev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
/Users/kev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:155:in `sh'
/Users/kev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:70:in `build_gem'
/Users/kev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:39:in `block in install'
/Users/kev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/kev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => release => build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Did you solve it, Kevin? I am running into the same problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem attempting to build a gem.  Turns out I was using an out of date version of rubygems (2.2.5) with ruby 2.2.3. [Upgrading rubygems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download) solved it for me. Rvm has a command for this:

`$ rvm rubygems latest`